# Can material design give a unique identity to my application?

Tags: mobile-application, material-design

Can material design be personalized in a way that gives identity to the app?
what I know about MDC (Material Design Components, an acronym I've just known!) is that it provides us with a bunch of ready-to-use controls, but doesn't this make all apps look like each other, with no different identity? or Material design is a general UI/UX concept that can embrace any idea and UI type?
I'm interesting in mobile applications design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Material Design is just a guideline.

From the Material Design footer:

> Material is an adaptable system of guidelines, components, and tools that support the best practices of user interface design.

Every component can be themed for example according to brand.
https://material.io/design/material-theming/overview.html#

> Material Design comes designed with a built-in, baseline theme that can be used as-is, straight out of the proverbial box. You can then customize it as little, or as much, as you like to make Material work for your product.

There are examples of this theming on every components page in Material Design. These examples are based on seven different [Material studies](https://material.io/design/material-studies/about-our-material-studies.html).

Here are the themes for button: https://material.io/design/components/buttons.html#theming